# Having a Parent-Children class hierarchy, how can I hold various actual children in a single "Parent"-typed variable?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

Let's say I have 4 classes:

1. Parent
2. child1
3. child2
4. child3

All of the children are descendants of the class parent.

In my toy program I have to create a separate variable for each child and then process what needs to be processed.  But I would like to have a variable that is of type parent that can casted as a child.

**Here's my current solution:**

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Child1 c1 = Child1();
    Child2 c2 = Child2();
    Child3 c3 = Child3();

    switch(arg[1]) {
         case CHILD1:
             c1.start();
             break;
         case CHILD2:
             c2.start();
             break;
         case CHILD3:
             c3.start();
             break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Here's the type of solution I'm looking to get to:**

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Parent p = Parent();

    switch(arg[1]) {
         case CHILD1:
             (Child1)p.start();
             break;
         case CHILD2:
             (Child2)p.start();
             break;
         case CHILD3:
             (Child3)p.start();
             break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I know the above isn't correct code.  But I think it properly conveys what I'm trying to get at.  I don't want to waste the memory for creating objects that aren't ever used.

Comment: Why do you create all objects before you know what you need? Create them within the switch, and that´s it.

Comment: You need a [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Comment: If you're not asking about anything related to fork, it is probably a bad idea to use the words "parent" and "child".  If your question is about inheritance, "base class" and "sub class" are good phrases.

Comment: You should have a switch in a factory method solely. Such method will take an ID and from that create a proper object for you, and return such object through a parent class pointer.

Comment: Is `start` a virtual method in `Parent`?

Comment: lilott8 - I found your original title of the question quite vague. I tried to make your title more specific to your actual problem. Please review the new title and feel free to change/improve or even revert back to previous if you don't agree.

Comment: BTW, `switch` statement can't use strings

Comment: @quetzalcoatl, thanks for the title edit. That is much better.

Comment: @ChrisDrew, those are enumerated types in the switch statement, I just didn't declare them for simplicity's sake (and didn't show the conversion) and because they weren't part of the core of my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea one: create the items in the switch

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    switch(arg[1]) {
         case CHILD1:
             {
                 Child1 p;
                 p.start();
                 break;
             }
         case CHILD2:
             {
                 Child2 p;
                 p.start();
                 break;
             }
         case CHILD3:
             {
                 Child3 p;
                 p.start();
                 break;
             }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Seems like a lot of code is copy-pasted right?  Right.  If your `Parent` has a virtual destructor and a virtual `start` method, you can use a factory pattern, which minimizes duplication.

```
std::unique_ptr<Parent> child_factory(char*) {
    switch(arg[1]) {
    case CHILD1: return std::make_unique<Child1>();
    case CHILD2: return std::make_unique<Child2>();
    case CHILD3: return std::make_unique<Child3>();
    default: throw std::runtime_error("invalid child type");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::unique_ptr<Parent> p = child_factory(arg[1]);
    p->start();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  I don't really know much about virtual methods so I'll have to go read up on them.  I spend most of my time in the Java world.  Which makes it super easy to solve this.  But this problem has to be solved in C/C++.  (And sadly, I didn't even think to turn this into a factory method :( #failure)

Comment: @lilott8: yeah, in Java every method is automatically virtual (except for static ones, well). In C++ you need to explicitely mark them as virtual, or they won't be.

Answer (score 1):

If those objects don't need to live very long, then you could simply do:

```
switch(arg[1]) {
     case CHILD1:
     {
         Child1 c1;
         c1.start();
         break;
     }
     case CHILD2:
     {
         Child2 c2;
         c2.start();
         break;
     }
     case CHILD3:
     {
         Child3 c3;
         c3.start();
         break;
     }
}
```

On the other hand, if you need to keep something around for longer and in terms of the `Parent` type, then you need to look into dynamically allocated objects assigned to a pointer of the base type. In that case, you probably want the `start` method to be `virtual`. Then you could do:

```
Parent* p = NULL;

switch(arg[1]) {
     case CHILD1:
         p = new Child1;
         break;
     case CHILD2:
         p = new Child2;
         break;
     case CHILD3:
         p = new Child3;
         break;
}

p.start();

// more stuff

delete p;
```

Of course, there's lots of room for improvement here, such as handling the situation where `arg[1]` doesn't match any of the cases. Also best practice would be to use a smart pointer for `p` so that deallocation is taken care of more reliably.

Comment: I kept it a toy example because I didn't care about the showing the error checking and the case handling.  I have all of that in my actual program.  I just couldn't figure out the object reuse -- which was really frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

The casting syntax isn't `(Child)p.start()`, but it's `((Child)p).start()`. The former would mean `(Child) (p.start())` so it would cast the value returned by start, not the P.

Anyways, casting is not needed at all since all of them are derived from 'Parent'. Read about virtual methods. With them, you can do something like:

```
Parent p = ...

p.start();  // the virtual method 'start' takes care of calling the right code
```

However #1: there is no free lunch. Virtual methods make sure that child's method is called when you call 'start' on parent, but something still must choose the correct child1/child2/child3 depending on the arg[1].

```
Parent p = chooseTheChild( arg[1] );   // you need to write it..

p.start();  // the virtual method 'start' takes care of calling the right code
```

However #2: it will not work on plain Parent. Virtual methods work on **pointers**.

```
Parent* p = chooseTheChild( arg[1] );   // you need to write it..

p->start();  // the virtual method 'start' takes care of calling the right code
```

Now you can write the 'choose' function.. No free lunch again, still a switch. And since pointers are needed, you have to `new` the child:

```
class Parent
{
    public:
        ~Parent() { }
        virtual void start() = 0;
};

class Child1 : public Parent
{
    public:
        virtual void start() { std::cout << "start1!" << std::endl; }
};

class Child2 : public Parent
{
    public:
        virtual void start() { std::cout << "start2!" << std::endl; }
};

class Child3 : public Parent
{
    public:
        virtual void start() { std::cout << "start3!" << std::endl; }
};

Parent* chooseTheChild( ChildType ttt)
{
  switch(ttt) {
     case CHILD1: return new Child1();
     case CHILD2: return new Child2();
     case CHILD3: return new Child3();
  }
}

.. somewhere ...

Parent* p = chooseTheChild( arg[1] );
p->start();  // the virtual method 'start' takes care of calling the right code
delete p;  // new'ed? delete it when finished!
```

This code is a sketch and is not meant to be 100% correct and clean, but should give you some things to play with. For example, smart pointers instead of plain pointers are obviosly needed.. etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but this definitively thinking inheritance the wrong way.  The relationship between *parent* and *children* can be thought of: *child_object* ***is a*** *parent_object*,  which means *child_object* can also be **used as a** *parent_object*, i.e. a can be casted,  called, … as one but **not vice versa!**

Mooing Duck's second example is good stuff.

Comment: I don't get your point. What OP asks for is classic abstract base and polymorphic implementations. That's totally along OOP and liskov's rule. Rename Parent to "IChild" or "Childbase" or "CommonChildInterface" if the naming prevents you from seeing it. Please review you answer and consider adding more arguments.

Comment: @qquetzalcoatl What ua2b is saying is a derived object can be used as a base object but you can't cast a base object to a child which is what OP was trying to do their second example.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is just to create the child when you need it. You can use a function template to eliminate duplicate code if you like:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Child1{
  void start() { std::cout << "Start Child1\n"; }    
};
struct Child2{
  void start() { std::cout << "Start Child2\n"; }    
};
struct Child3{
  void start() { std::cout << "Start Child3\n"; }    
};

template<typename Child>
void start() {
  auto child = Child();
  child.start();
}    

int main(int /*argc*/, char* argv[]) {
  auto type = std::string(argv[1]);
  if (type == "CHILD1")
      start<Child1>();
  else if (type == "CHILD2")
      start<Child2>();
  else if (type == "CHILD3")
      start<Child3>();
}
```

In this particular case there is no need to have `virtual` methods if you don't want to but in a more complicated case you might want to have a factory that returns a (smart) pointer to `Parent` and have a virtual destructor and start method on `Parent`.